# Find command ignore directory

Tags: linux, directory, find

I am trying to find  all files ending in .jar, but it is picking up folders that ends in .jar which is something I do not want.

My command so far

```
find . -name ".*jar"
```

I need it so it ignores directories ending in .jar

Additional request.

I now need to ignore a specific folder when looking, is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add -type f:

```
find . -name "*.jar" -type f
```

Comment: Also it should probably be `"*.jar"` instead of `".*jar"`.

Comment: This worked fine. An additional request too. How to ignore a specific folder when searching?

Answer (score 2):

Others have already shown, how to pick up files named ending in `.jar`. As an answer to your comment "How to ignore a specific folder". You use `-prune` for that

```
find . -name 'specific/folder' -type d -prune -o -type f -name '*.jar'
```

Answer (score 0):

that's what you want

```
find . -type f -name "*.jar"
```

see man page:

```
-type Type
    Evaluates to the value True if the Type variable specifies one of the following values:
      b
           Block special file
      c
           Character special file
      d
           Directory
      f
           Plain file
      l
           Symbolic link
      p
           FIFO (a named pipe)
      s
           Socket
```